# Embedd CSS Images as Base64 with Gulp/SCSS and @import

Tags: sass, gulp, base64

I have some SCSS files that are part of a modular theme. So they need to be included using `@import`. They also contain some css background images, which should be embedded as base64. In short, the problem is that no gulp base64 plugin seems to be avaliable to resolve correct paths if the backgrund image is in a sub file that got included using `@import`.

#### File structure

[image: code_2018-09-12_16-19-12]

#### sub/sub.scss

`.my-image {
    background: url(sprite/9_2018_ohne.jpg);
}`

#### test.scss

`@import "sub/sub";`

#### gulpfile

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='sass, sass-watch' />
const gulp = require("gulp"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  sass = require("gulp-sass"),
  cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css"),
  sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
  noop = require("gulp-noop"),
  header = require("gulp-header"),
  cssBase64 = require("gulp-css-base64");

const srcFolder = "src";
const productionBuild = false;

let bundle = {
  sassFiles: [`src/test.scss`],
  output: {
    file: "main.css",
    folder: "."
  }
};
let cleanCssOptions = {
  compatibility: "ie11",
  debug: true,
  level: 2
};

gulp.task("css", () => {
  let headerNotice = `/* test*/`;

  return gulp
    .src(bundle.sassFiles)
    .pipe(productionBuild ? noop() : sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(
      cssBase64({
        //baseDir: "img",
        maxWeightResource: 100000000000
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      productionBuild ? cleanCSS(cleanCssOptions) : noop()
    )

    .pipe(rename(bundle.output.file))
    .pipe(productionBuild ? sourcemaps.write() : noop())
    .pipe(header(headerNotice))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bundle.output.folder));
});
```

Generated css result:

`css
.my-image {
  background: url(sprite/9_2018_ohne.jpg); }`

If I place the background directive directly in `test.scss` it works well as expected:

`css
.my-image {
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64, ...);`

Installed Packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.4",
    "gulp-header": "^2.0.5",
    "gulp-noop": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp-css-base64": "^1.3.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that base64 encoding does not work properly. The path of the sprite in the file `sub.scss` is not the right one, it would be necessary that the path is `sub/sprite/9_2018_ohne.jpg`.

```
.my-image {
    background: url(sub/sprite/9_2018_ohne.jpg);
}
```

The CSS is rendered from the file `test.scss` and changes the hierarchy of the paths.